Are pointers addresses in C?
I always assumed that the & operator gives the address of the memory a variable is pointing to. I am currently looking at the MPI standard documentation and found the following, which confused me.

however, that & cast-expression is a pointer, not an address. ISO C does not require that the value of a pointer (or the pointer cast to int) be the absolute address of the object pointed at --- although this is commonly the case


In practice pointers are addresses (except perhaps on some very obscure platforms), but there are additional restrictions attached to them (the compilers can optimize with the assumption that you don't do certain things, e.g. don't violate strict aliasing).
The way C/C++ standards document those restrictions is by explaining pointers as some abstract entities (not mentioning addresses at all), and documenting what operations are allowed on them (a subset of what you could if they were just addresses).
Some people really like to say "pointers are not addresses!" to highlight the existence of those additional restrictions, but this is a rather confusing way to put it, and I prefer the "addresses with some restrictions" mental model.

As an example of a platform where pointers are not addresses: in WASM they are indexes in a linear memory array. This means, for example, that 0 is a valid pointer in WASM and that memory can be read and written to. It also means that 0 is the 'first byte' of memory, and 1 is the 'second byte' of memory. Though practically speaking an index is basically just a virtual address :)

@Chad ¯\(ツ)/¯ This fits my definition of an "address". If you're running an emulator, I'd still call its emulated addresses "addresses". "practically speaking an index is basically just a virtual address" Exactly. :)

@Chad why would 0 not be a valid address? It is just C convention to regard NULL to be invalid. In many embedded systems I worked with, that was a valid address.

In many non-embedded systems 0 is not an address you can read from or write to. It is protected. I was mentioning this is not true on WASM, contrary to most platforms.
